# How to keep two svn branches still track after changing them into one git repository?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Suppose I have a project root directory called Root, and there are two directories Root/A and Root/B under it. I used svn to manage this project before, and B is the svn branch of A (created using `svn cp`). Now the project has been migrated to git using `git svn`, while the entire Root directory becomes a git repository.
I have encountered two problems which bother me for days:

1. How can I make directory B continue to track A just like before, which means I can `cd B` and `merge` modifications of A?
2. Another problem is that before the project was migrated to git, the A directory still has some svn commits that are not merged into the B directory. How should I find these changes now and merge them into the B directory?

Thanks for your advice and help!

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the GitHub help page "[Splitting a subfolder out into a new repository](https://help.github.com/en/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository)".

- In the second repository, you will have `B` folder history in its own branch.
- In the first repository, you can:

  - `git rm B`
  - [move `A` folder content to `/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3212697/6309)

Once completed, you can fetch that history of the new repository into your existing repository: you will have your legacy branch, and your new branch.

That assume your SVN repository is ready to be exported: see for instance "[Subversion: howto find all revisions that are not merged to trunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2220822/6309)" for your second question.